# Изменить размер изображения в Xamarin Forms

Tags: изображения, xamarin, forms, resize

Собственно, как изменить размер изображения в *Xamarin Forms* и сохранить как новый файл.
Уже имеется `MediaFile`, который был получен с помощью плагина `Xam.Plugins` от *jamesmontemagno* и из него нужно сделать второй файл, а конкретней - уменьшенное изображение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовывал такое через платформа зависимый код. 
К примеру код в iOS проекте будет работать с UIImage
хороший пример описан в этом посте 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4170/resize-images-and-save-thumbnails

Также можете задавать тут качество выходной картинки через UIImage.

Дальше через DependencyService получаете доступ к этим методом.

Comment: Ну то, что это через платформо-зависимы код делается - это понятно было. А вот именно для Android'a как он будет выглядеть?

Comment: @project AZinX   https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/XamFormsImageResize/

public static byte[] ResizeImageAndroid (byte[] imageData, float width, float height)
  {
   // Load the bitmap
   Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
   Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)width, (int)height, false);

   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
    resizedImage.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
    return ms.ToArray ();
   }
  }